# multi lingual url's with encoding issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encoding, localization, multilingual

I have an asp.net mvc 4 web application that is multi lingual. For SEO purposes, Url's are localized to the language of the site.

This has caused some issues, in particular for Cyrillic. The url's end up weird encoding in the address bar and in the markup. Url's generated from action links also have such encoding.

Any way to prevent this and ensure that url's continue with text that is non encoded and would mean more to the end user?